# Constants of Integration In Hamilton-Jacobi theory

Tags: terminology, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, integrals-of-motion

I have had this confusion for a while now. We solve the Hamilton Jacobi equation,

$$H+\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=0$$

Say we get a solution $S(q,\alpha,t)$ where $\alpha$ is a **constant of integration**. The approach is then to identity $\alpha$ as the new momentum.

I have trouble understanding this,
when we define $\alpha$ as the new momentum, is $\alpha(p,q,t)$? Is $\alpha$ a **function** of the old co-ordinates and time? My understanding is that $\alpha$ is a constant, a number which is determined by the initial conditions we give and we try to invert the solutions locally in HJ approach.

And what is the difference between a constant of integration and constant of motion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the logic is as follows:

1. The [HJ equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is a first-order non-linear PDE in $n+1$ variables $(q^1,\ldots q^n,t)$, which may in principle be solved using e.g. the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). A complete$^1$ solution $S(q,\alpha,t)$ has $n$ non-trivial$^2$ [constants of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration) $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. Hamilton's principal function $S(q,\alpha,t)$ is a [type-2 generating function for a CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) $(q,p,t)\to (Q,P,t)$, which (among other things) implies that
   $$ p_i ~=~\frac{\partial S}{\partial q^i} ~=~\text{function of } (q,\alpha,t).\tag{1}$$
3. A complete$^1$ solution has by definition
   $$ \det\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial q^i\alpha_j}~\neq~ 0, \tag{2}$$
   so that the relation (1) can in principle be solved for $\alpha$, which then becomes a function of $(q,p,t)$.
4. The constants of integration $\alpha$ are next identified with the new momenta $P$.
5. The Kamiltonian $K\equiv 0$ vanishes identically, so that the new phase space variables $(Q,P)$ are [constants of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion), cf. Kamilton's equations. The definition of a constant of motion in a Hamiltonian context is given in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/510024/2451).

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Section 10.1 first footnote.
2. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *Mechanics,* vol. 1 (1976); $\S$47 footnote on p. 148.

--

$^1$ A [complete solution to a 1st-order PDE is *not* a general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation#General_solution_and_complete_integral) [1,2], despite the name!

$^2$ There is also a trivial constant of integration $\alpha_0$ associated with a shift $S\to S+\alpha_0$, which we suppress.

Comment: Can we set $\alpha_1=p^{1}(0)$? I mean to ask if we can designate $\alpha_i$ with initial momentum?