# Additive constant in Hamilton-Jacobi theory?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, differential-equations

In Hamilton-Jacobi theory Hamilton's principal function $S$ is a function of $n+1$ constants. But we take one of the $n+1$ constants as an additive constant. I don't get this step?

Answer (score 2):

The [HJ equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is a non-linear [first-order PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation) for $S$ in $(n+1)$ variables $(q^1, \ldots, q^n, t)$, but the PDE does not depend on $S$ directly, only its derivatives. Therefore one additive integration constant $S\to S+\alpha_{n+1}$ is trivial.

For more information, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398937/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: PDE in (n+1) variables implies we need ( n+1) constants to find complete solution . if we set one constant as additive and solve PDE in n constants , How this will bring a complete solution?

Comment: Why don't $S= S+\alpha_n+\alpha_{n+1}$ @Qmechanic