# Hamilton-Jacobi Theory: Can we take 2 additive constants?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, differential-equations

I am thinking continuously regarding the additive constant in Hamilton-Jacobi theory. But I didn't get a good idea. Why only one additive constant, can we take 2 or 3 additive constants?
$$S=S'+\alpha_n+\alpha_{n+1}.  $$

Answer (score 0):

A [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation#General_solution_and_complete_integral) solution $$S(q^1,\ldots,q^n,t;\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n+1})$$ to the [Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) should by definition satisfy
$$ \det \frac{\partial^2S}{\partial(q,t)\partial\alpha}~\neq~0.\tag{*}$$
If 2 or more $\alpha$ constants enter the solution $S$ in the same manner, e.g. additively, then 2 or more columns in the above matrix would be the same, thereby violating the condition (*).

For more information, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398937/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437141/2451) related Phys.SE posts.